# log-scaled density plot: ggplot2 and freqpoly, but with points instead of lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

What I really want to do is plot a histogram, with the y-axis on a log-scale.  Obviously this i a problem with the `ggplot2` `geom_histogram`, since the bottom os the bar is at zero, and the log of that gives you trouble.

My workaround is to use the `freqpoly geom`, and that more-or less does the job.  The following code works just fine:

```
ggplot(zcoorddist) + 
  geom_freqpoly(aes(x=zcoord,y=..density..),binwidth = 0.001) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

The issue is that at the edges of my data, I get a couple of garish vertical lines that really thro you off visually when combining a bunch of these freqpoly curves in one plot.  What I'd like to be able to do is use points at every vertex of the freqpoly curve, and no lines connecting them.  Is there a way to to this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get the desired plot is to just recast your data. Then you can use `geom_point`. Since you don't provide an example, I used the standard example for `geom_histogram` to show this:

```
# load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
# get data
data(movies)
movies <- movies[, c("title", "rating")]
# here's the equivalent of your plot
ggplot(movies) + geom_freqpoly(aes(x=rating, y=..density..), binwidth=.001) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
# recast the data
df1 <- recast(movies, value~., measure.var="rating")
names(df1) <- c("rating", "number")
# alternative way to recast data
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(movies$rating))
names(df2) <- c("rating", "number")
df2$rating <- as.numeric(as.character(df$rating))
# plot
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=rating)) + scale_y_continuous(trans="log10", name="density") 
# with lines
p + geom_linerange(aes(ymax=number, ymin=.9))
# only points
p + geom_point(aes(y=number))
```

Comment: Note to people who see this years later: ggplot2 no longer contains the movies dataset.  It's its own package, ggplot2movies.  Install and call it, then data(movies) works.